# What can I use to fix a gap between the light fixture and the ceiling?

Tags: lighting, junction-box, lath-and-plaster

It's a very old house that the ceiling is made out of lath and plaster so it would be too much work to dig a hole to put in a large junction box for the wires. They won't fit in the base of the light fixture so it leaves a 1 inch gap.

What could I use to blend it in and make this work?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some pictures would be helpful; if you can't edit them into your question, edit in the URLs and someone will be along to edit in the pictures.

Comment: See http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/523/22 for instructions on how to add a photo to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Wires and connections must be contained in an enclosure that is designed for that purpose. You might be able to find a decorative canopy extension ring at a good lighting and/or fan shop. it might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: That is a pancake box used for wiremold. While this could work, I am interested to see what the ceiling looks like to see if there is a proper box there or not.

Comment: @Jason Hutchinson, yup that's exactly what that is.That is why I said *"it might look something like this"*. I was too lazy to spend the time searching for what I really think he needs because he's been too lazy to post a picture.